Why is warming food in the microwave work and not heat?
In Schroeder's An Introduction to Thermal Physics, heat is defined as the "spontaneous flow of energy from one object to another" and work is defined thermodynamically as any other transfer of energy into or out of a system.
Schroeder then goes on to say

"The definitions of heat and work are not easy to internalize, because both of these words have very different meanings in everyday language. It is strange to think that there is no "heat" entering your hands when you rub them together to warm them up, or entering a cup of tea that you are warming in the microwave. Nevertheless both of these processes are classified as work, not heat."

However, Schroeder goes on to say that there are three processes of heat transfer: conduction, convection, and radiation.
Is heating an object in a microwave not an example of radiation? It is not obvious to me why this process is considered work and not heat. Is it because the process of starting the microwave is not spontaneous? And if so, why is this process not spontaneous?
Also, what is happening at a micro level here. To me, it seems like the food is being heated in two ways. First, some of the energy from the radiation in the microwave is heating the air molecules, which are themselves heating the food by conduction. Second, some of the energy from the radiation of the microwave is not being absorbed by the air molecules but is instead directly being absorbed by the food. Is this accurate?

I'd have thought that "spontaneous flow of energy from one object to another" isn't enough to define heat. Surely one needs to add "due to the first object being at a higher temperature than the second". Your difficulty with the microwave oven then goes away: the oven isn't usually hotter than what you'r warming in it.

Does this answer your question? Microwaves: why do they cook food?

Work is done by a - more or less - more by design, less by reality of costs - coherent wave and as such it has very little entropy so it cannot really be called "heat" in any sense the  word "heat" might mean. The magnetron's effective temperature is expressed in the phase noise of the magnetron and at worst its spectral width may not exceed the allocated bandwidth ~75MHz around 2.45GHz, that is about 3% and thermally speaking is insignificant.

@PhilipWood you're right, I misremembered the definition from the book and it actually does include that clause. But I'm curious why that clause is necessary.
Can't energy only flow from the first object to the second spontaneously if the first object is at a higher temperature than the second? Isn't this implied by the definition of temperature as
$\frac{1}{T} \equiv \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial U} \right)_{N,V}$?
